# Conversão de um resultado do mysqli_query() para String

Tags: php

***Primeiro, não sou bom escrevendo, mas vou tentar explicar o problema***

Eu preciso imprimir somente uma célula(quantidade de votos já feitos) da tabela do resultado da query, mas não to conseguindo acessar o valor da erro de conversão.

eu estava tendo da fazer a consulta e da o echo direto na chamada da função no html

Os votos precisam esta depois da descrição do nome

```
function pegarQtdVotos($conexao,$classificacao){
    $query = "select qtd_votos from VOTOS where id={$classificacao}";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);
    $qtd = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
    return $qtd;
}
```

```html
<p class="alert-success"><input type="radio" name="classificacao" id="classificacao" value="1"> Execelente</p>
<p class="alert-info"><input type="radio" name="classificacao" id="classificacao" value="2"> Bom </p>
<p class="alert-warning"><input type="radio" name="classificacao" id="classificacao" value="3"> Regular </p>
<p class="alert-danger"><input type="radio" name="classificacao" id="classificacao" value="4"> Ruim </p>
```

Comment: $query = "select qtd_votos from VOTOS where id={$classificacao}"; $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $query); while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) { echo $rows['qtd_votos'];};

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado... eu queria fazer esse while na outra pagina, mas quando eu já imprimo dentro da função funcionou... obrigado...
@LeoCaracciolo
**coloca o código na resposta da pergunta**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você imprimir dentro da função vai funcionar!

```
function pegarQtdVotos($conexao,$classificacao){

   $query="select qtd_votos from VOTOS where id={$classificacao}"; 
   $resultado=mysqli_query($conexao,$query);

   $qtd = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);

   //return $qtd;    
   echo $qtd["qtd_votos"];

}
```

O `while` é a estrutura de repetição mais simples do PHP. Com ele informamos que um bloco de código deve ser repetido enquanto a condição declarada for verdadeira.

```
$query = "select qtd_votos from VOTOS where id={$classificacao}"; 
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $query); 
 while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) { 
   echo $rows['qtd_votos'];
};
```